# Cheating university in the name of university campus in Malaysia.

Tags: university, cheating

Can any higher educational institution use 'university campus' title for their unnamed building when they run franchise program from UK university?

Nottingham Ran Franchise

https://www.timeshighereducation.com/news/tribunal-says-nottingham-ran-franchise/310368.article

Nottingham University UK, Malaysia campus is a Malaysian university.

http://www.gen-e-resources.com/themalaysianuniversity.pdf

Comment: Do you mean to ask whether a foreign university can ethically claim that a locally run and operated university is part of their franchise? Or do you mean to ask whether a local university can bear a foreign university's name just for branding?

Comment: You've obviously got some complaint about Nottingham Uni but posting nonsensical questions doesn't help.

Comment: As someone who understands the issues with UoN, the question almost makes sense.

Comment: Having read the OP's post elsewhere he certainly seems to have a very valid complaint against UoN and the non-award of his PhD. However the question here is not relevant. [In the interests of fairness I'll also say his approach to resolution has not been great.]

Comment: @StrongBad since you understand the question, can you edit it so it makes sense to the rest of us?

Comment: @ff524 I said "almost" makes sense. The way UoN setup its international campuses was very deliberate. There is an interesting question buried in there. I am hoping the OP will care enough to dig out his/her question and not just rant against the university.

Answer (score 1):

*DISCLAIMER: I used to work at the University of Nottingham UK campus in a school that was located on both the UK and MY campuses.*

As is clear from the law suit described in the linked THE article, it is non-trivial for a university to set up a franchise. The parent university can get sued and therefore needs to take care in setting up the franchise. Presumable, any university with enough legal resources can set up a franchise

There are at least three different types of issues with running a international campus. The first, of which I have little understanding, is related to income, assets, taxes, liabilities, etc. The second is related to staffing (both faculty and support staff). The third is related to students. Setting up the university as a franchise affects the financial issues and the staffing, but really does not directly affect the students.

By setting up a franchise, UoN may be cheating the UK government out of taxes, but it is not cheating its staff, faculty, or students.

By being a franchise, this means that faculty are employed in MY and not the UK. This means they are governed by MY labor laws and not UK/EU laws. From the university perspective, this means that if a school in MY performs poorly that they can close the school and do not need to bring the faculty back to the UK. To an extent UoN is cheating the faculty in MY in that they do not get the same pay and benefits as UK faculty, but the UoN makes this clear during the hiring process. This is what the law suit reported in the THE is about.

There is no effect of being a franchise on students. In my former school, all MY faculty needed to be "appointable" in the UK campus. This mean that if they applied for a UK position and were the best candidate, that they would be offered a job. At least one UK faculty member is on all MY search committees. While there are slight differences in the teaching materials, the modules, coursework, and exams, and marking guidelines are identical for the two campuses. The two campuses shared a common exam board. The school on the MY campus was accredited by the same UK accrediting body that accredits the UK campus. In fact the MY school was the first international school to be accredited. The two campuses even share the same Quality Manual:

> The provisions of the Quality Manual and any other University regulations regarding the quality management of learning and teaching apply equally to the University’s campuses in the UK and Asia.

Comment: The exams are identical? That's interesting. Is different instructors offering the same exam pretty normal in UK universities?